# How could one define the exact data types at any level of a nested object / array data-structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, types

I am trying to define a "complex" object:

```
var tM = JSON.parse('{"version":"","series":[{"name":"","possModes":[],"instance":[{"date":"","mode":""}]}]}');
```

where **all** items of array "instance" should be objects of type

```
{"date":"","mode":""}
```

and **all** items of array "series" should be objects of type

```
{"name":"","possModes":[],"instance":[{"date":"","mode":""}]}
```

The problem is that only the items of index [0] are getting the proper properties and items of higher indexes are "undefined", so I cannot set them to their needed values.

I have also tried to define `tM` explicitly, like:

```
var Cinstance = new Object();
Cinstance.date = "";
Cinstance.mode = "";

var Cseries = new Object();
Cseries.name = '';
Cseries.possModes = [];
Cseries.instance = [new Object(Cinstance)];

var tM= new Object();
tM.version = "";
tM.series = [new Object(Cseries)];
```

and also like:

```
var tM = {series:
           [{instance:
              [{date:"",mode:""}
              ]
            }
           ]
         }
```

(this is a version reduced to my specific problem).

Of course, they both end up with the same result  - only items of index [0] are defined.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a notion of types like this. If you want compile-time checking of this kind, you can use languages like TypeScript and Flow.

Comment: Thanks H.M. for the prompt response.
Just to make myself clear - I can do without "compile-time checking of this kind". 
What I do need is a way to define an array of objects. When yo say "compile-time checking of this kind" - do you mean "there is no way in javascript to define an array of objects"?

Comment: firstly `JSON.stringify(tM.series[0])` returns exactly what you did ask for ... `'{"name":"","possModes":[],"instance":[{"date":"","mode":""}]}'`; secondly, neither `new Object(Cinstance)` nor `new Object(Cseries)` create new instances, instead one just gets returned the original references of `Cinstance` respectively `Cseries`. Please take some time to precisely write to yourself in short sentences what your incoming data is or does represent and which kind of data structure you want to **create** ? / **validate** ? upon the former.

Comment: Hello Peter. Thanks for helping out.
I want to define an array of objects of a specific type.
In this specific case, one array of objects {date: "", mode: ""}
and another array where all items are objects of type "series" as I tried to define them.

Comment: In case javascript does not provide the syntax to define an array of objects, is there a workaround under which I can "force" it at the time of assigning values or before assigning the values?
If so, can you direct me to an example?

Comment: In case you want to define a schema of how your structure has to be build, have a look into [**JSON Schema**](https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step). One already gets validation of object structures for free. And in case you want to  dynamically generate your own constructors/factories for each of your involved types, parsing such a scheme and building stuff on top of the parsing result is much easier than coming up with your own JSON-based type-description and a special parsing process on top of all that.

Comment: Thanks again Peter. I'll look into the JSON Schema

Answer (score 0):

The data structure provided by the OP ...

```
{
  "version": "",
  "series": [{

    "name": "",
    "possModes": [],
    "instance": [{

      "date": "",
      "mode": ""
    }]
  }]
}
```

... [**does validate**](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/aKFnhcE9) against the following [*JSON schema*](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html) ...

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "My-Special-Schema-Or-Data-Structure-Title",
  "description": "Whatever I have to say about my described structure",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "version": {
      "description": " ... ",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "series": {
      "description": " ... ",
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "description": " ... ",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "possModes": {
            "description": " ... ",
            "type": "array"
          },
          "instance": {
            "description": " ... ",
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": {
              "description": " ... ",
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "date": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "mode": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "date",
                "mode"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "name",
          "possModes",
          "instance"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "version",
    "series"
  ]
}
```

There is even a [JSON Schema Generator](https://extendsclass.com/json-schema-validator.html) one could start with. Passing the OP's originally provided data structure, one gets a solid base of a JSON Schema, one then can continue tailoring.

Comment: Hi Peter. Following the links you left in your answer I dug deeper into the subject and learned plenty. The schema '"title": "My-Special-Schema-Or-Data-Structure-Title"' you defined does represent the structure I need. What I am missing and couldn't find in my searches is how I turn this schema definition into a javascript object that I can use in my code. For example, assign a value, such as: 
tM.series[0].instances[1].mode = "Mode 1";

Comment: @Oded ... What you want to achieve is only possible if one has some requirements to follow or an established way of how assumptions can be made. Just from the scheme nobody and thus also not a program can guess which substructures are the ones that need to be created again and again. This kind of information has to be shipped as additional information within e.g. kind of custom config object. Another Q. which arises is, how does a process or person which/who is going to trigger/invoke an object creation "know" about the correct argument types.

Comment: @Oded ... Having said the above, maybe you could provide a bigger picture of what you're actually trying to build/achieve.

Comment: I come from the disciplines where you can define a "Structure" that is built of arrays and substructures (C++, C, PL/1). Usually, the arrays in these languages are of fixed length. When I started to code in JavaScript  I was happy to se that all arrays are of varying length (I guess JavaScript manages them as indexed lists). Well, as you mentioned above, this is not possible and one has to manage these kind of structures as "simple" objects, where the programmer has to construct the nested objects as part of the process.

Comment: "... how does a process or person which/who is going to trigger/invoke an object creation "know" about the correct argument types" - this is the responsibility of the programmer.

Comment: "... provide a bigger picture of what you're actually trying to build/achieve" - The user can manage several seies with several instances in each series. An instance can be for example a "workout". When the user decides to document a workout they choose the mode of this instance ("possMode" - e.g. Running, Walking, Aerobics) and the program records the date and the "mode" of the instancet. This structures allows the user to manage several "series" (e.g. "workout", "Music Practice", "Toll payment").
"Version" is for managing future upgrades of the schema.